# I am reading a bin file using MATLAB and python. They are reading header differently

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to read a binary file using MATLAB and python. MATLAB is producing header

[80  0   8   0   1780    400   357   22441]      whereas python is reading the header

[   80     8   1780   357   258 22440  2040  2048].

What is the wrong I am doing???  I am running both on windows.

```
**MATLAB code:** 
    fid = fopen(file_name);
    fread(fid,isTherePos(1)-1,'uint32','l'); 
    header = fread(fid,8,'uint16','l')
```

```
**Python code:** 
     with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
       b = f.read()
       np_data = np.frombuffer(b, dtype='<I')
       srtOfLine = LidarMRC.findStartOfLine(filename)
       header = np_data[srtOfLine[0][0]:srtOfLine[0][0] +8].astype('<H')
       print(header)
```

Comment: Where did np_data come from, exactly?  Did you open it with 'r' or 'rb'?

Comment: I opened it with 'rb'.

Comment: You only answered half of my question.  How did you create np_data?

Comment: Oh, sorry!  here is the code :     `with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
            b = f.read()
        np_data = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.uint32)`

Comment: Do you not see how very different those are?  You're reading np_data as uint32 in Python, and as uint16 in Matlab.

Comment: @Tim . Okay.  I am reading the file uint32 then for header it's unit16. Below is my MATLAB code.   ` fid = fopen(file_name);`
`fread(fid,isTherePos(1)-1,'uint32','l'); % reading line number 1`
`header = fread(fid,8,'uint16','l'); % headrer for line number 1`

Comment: Please don't make us guess.  Modify your question to include a complete, runnable example that shows you opening the file, reading the file, and printing the header through both methods.

Comment: Have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MATLAB code, you read the first "isTherePos(1)-1" bytes as 32-bit values.  Then you read the header as 8x 16-bit values.

In the Python code, you read the whole file into np_data as 32-bit values.  The "astype" function does not re-interpret those bytes.  It takes each 32-bit entity and truncates it to 16 bits, which is exactly what you see.

You should read np_data as `dtype=np.uint16`, then adjust your srtOfLine number to multiply by 2.

Comment: Thank a lot @Tim. I have a question. What is the best way to read a .bin file the way like read 1byte-1byte-2bytes-2bytes-2bytes-1-byte-seek(some bytes) and go on ?

Comment: More specifically, I would like to read the file with different datatypes as require. I don't want to read the whole file at certain datatype  at the beginning . In MATLAB, we can do that using fread.

Comment: Python also has `read`, which serves the same purpose as `fread`.  You have just chosen to read the whole file as one chunk.  You don't have to do that.  You would use the `struct` module to decode the header.  `head = struct.unpack('BBHHHB', f.read(9))` / `f.seek(127)`

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Tim